# bitcoin JSON-RPC Api requests in React native?

Tags: react-native, bitcoin, json-rpc, bitcoind

How do i make a request in react-native to build wallet for bitcoin,bitcoind server running,but can't make any bitcoin json-rpc request in react native.

Answer (score -1):

Use  this api to interface it with react.  By changing some syntax

https://github.com/blockchain/service-my-wallet-v3